# Удаление margin у границы блока

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

Есть div flex-контейнер стили которого такие

```
width: 754px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

В нем есть div flex-блоки с картинками

```
margin-right: 20px;
```

Как сделать так чтобы flex-блоки прижимались к краям родительского блока, как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшой хак, а так по сути flex такое не любит.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: теперь последние два блока делят пространство ниже между собой